# Emails not being sent via PHPMailer

Tags: arrays, switch-statement, phpmailer

I took over the web development for a company and they've got a feedback form on a couple pages (**colorado**, **prescott**, **flagstaff** and **wyoming**) that submits form info to an email as a spam filter using PHPmailer. However, they're not receiving emails the way they hoped. I can get emails through all addAddress emails except for the one using **$recipeint**. Searched and tried everything I could think of including **explode** and **foreach** other codes. Can't get this to work. A little help would be great.

```
$colorado = array( "ColoradoSprings", "Denver", "Boulder" );
$colorado = array_map( 'strtolower', $colorado );

$wyoming = array( "Cheyenne", "Buffalo" );
$wyoming = array_map( 'strtolower', $wyoming );

if ( in_array( $_POST[ 'location' ], $colorado ) || in_array( $_POST[ 'location' ], $wyoming ) )
    $recipient = "person1@mail.com, person2@mail.com";

switch ( $_POST[ 'location' ] ) {
    case "prescott":
        $recipient = "person3@mail.com, person4@mail.com";
        break;
    case "flagstaff":
        $recipient = "person3@mail.com, person4@mail.com";


        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.com';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "senderemail@mail.com";
        $mail->Password = "password";
        $mail->setFrom( 'allmail@mail.com', 'Everyone' );
        $mail->addReplyTo( $_POST[ "Email" ], $_POST[ "Name" ] );
        $mail->addAddress( 'allmail@mail.com', 'Everyone' );
        $mail->addAddress( 'random@mail.com', 'John Doe' );
        $mail->addAddress( $recipient, 'Others' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is strange code, or incomplete. As it stands it will only attempt to send email if `location == 'flagstaff'`, so you probably need to pay some attention to your conditions.

`addAddress` only accepts a single address; if you want to send more, call it multiple times in a loop. For example:

```
$recipients = ["person1@mail.com", "person2@mail.com"];
foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
    $mail->addAddress($recipient);
}
```

Comment: Tried doing something like this:  
  
`$col_email= ["person1@mail.com", "person2@mail.com"];  
foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {  
    $mail->addAddress($recipient);  
}  
$pres_email= ["person3@mail.com", "person4@mail.com"];  
foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {  
    $mail->addAddress($recipient);  
}`  
  
but that just sent emails to all listed accounts instead of just the ones based on the page the feedback was submitted from.

Comment: That's a different problem - only send it to the people you want to send it to!